CMM - "Symbol not found" error message when running the IOS emulator
I created function to set specific orientation in iosmain:
 actual fun setPortraitOrientation() {
        val systemVersion = UIDevice.currentDevice.systemVersion

        val majorVersion = systemVersion.split(".").firstOrNull()?.toIntOrNull() ?: 0
        if (majorVersion >= 16) {
            // iOS 16 or later
            val windowScene = UIApplication.sharedApplication.connectedScenes.firstOrNull() as? UIWindowScene
            windowScene?.requestGeometryUpdateWithPreferences(
                UIWindowSceneGeometryPreferencesIOS().apply {
                    this.interfaceOrientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait
                },
                errorHandler = { error ->
                    // Optional: Handle any error that occurs here
                    println("Error updating orientation: ${error?.localizedDescription}")
                }
            )

        } else {
            UIDevice.currentDevice.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait.toLong(), forKey = "orientation")
        }
    }

Running with ios >= 16 version doesn't result in any errors. But when I run the emulator with ios 15.4 version, I get this error, even though this function will not be executed at runtime:
dyld[3635]: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIWindowSceneGeometryPreferencesIOS
How can I make the IDE ignore such errors during compilation?
